# list not displaying items

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have an issue with displaying items in a list view. I have tried to add Mode= twoway, oneway or default.

I have checked the binding

```
  <ListView x:Name="list"  
                        HasUnevenRows="True" 
                        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                       
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding DateFormatList}"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                   <Label Text="{Binding DateType}" TextColor="black" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="14" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  ></Label>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Back of my page

```
public DateSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new CustomSettingsViewModel();
        }
```

My Ctor in the view model

```
 public List<DateFormat> DateFormatList { get; private set; }
public CustomSettingsViewModel()
{
      
            DateFormatList = new List<DateFormat>();
            DateFormatList.Add(new DateFormat
            {
                DateType = "yy/dd/mm",
              
            });
}
```

Model

```
 public class DateFormat
    {
        public string DateType;
    }
```

Comment: `DateType` is not a property

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a while can you expand on your comment please

Comment: I have gone accrding to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/listview/?tutorial-step=2&tabs=vswin

Comment: you can only bind to public properties.  `DateType` is not a property.  Lookup "c# property" if you are not sure what that means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only bind to public properties

```
public class DateFormat
{
    public string DateType { get; set; }
}
```